# Async NSURLConnection with delegate pattern

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperation

I know this question has been asked a lot of time and a lot of suggestions exist on the net. But i am still not able to conclude what is the right way. 
After `ASIHTTPRequest` becoming obsolete, i think it is not advisable to use any third party libraries(though `AFNetworking` is really good), hence i am trying to build a one on my own.

1. I want to have following features in it Asynchronous concurrent
   connections
2. Support of delegate methods to track connection progress
3. Support of doing authentication
4. Ability to cancel any connection and restart

I did came across multiple recipes using `NSOperation`, GCD, `NSBlockOperation`, `NSRunLoop`, etc. Also i did check the code of `AFURLConnectionOperation` but it is hell lot of a code which i think can be over kill in many situations.

Can anyone suggest me the optimum and minimalist way to achieve my requirements?

Comment: Hi, M also facing the same issue. Please suggest.

Comment: If you want to utilize NSURLConnection (recommended) the core of the functionality of a network request class which is a subclass of NSOperation will be a minimum of about 1000 lines of code. That won't deal with multipart requests and many useful utilities, like Network Manager class, special response handlers (JSON, XML, image pre loaders, etc.)